# how to set a relationship after save button is pressed in another view controller?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am having trouble setting a relationship in code.

When the save button on 'Add Food To List' is pressed, I want to set the relationship for that food to be "heldBy" the list I am adding it to. What I have right now, in AddFoodToListTVC:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender
{


Food *food = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Food"

food.name = foodToListNameTextField.text;

[food setHeldBy:?????];
```

In layman's terms, I want to say "this food is held by the list that we were just looking at".

This is my first iOS project, sorry for the novice question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/KWVYF.png

sorry here's the picture

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't know how to use Storyboards, but I do know how to do something like that with pure code if you're open to this type of answer.

For a simple table view, there are two general rules you need to follow:

1) Tell the table how many rows it needs to display

2) Tell the table what elements you need to render in each cell

The number of rows in a table is usually defined by how many elements you have in an array that is declared in your View Controller's .h file.

Something like

```
// View Controller header file (.h file)
@interface
{
    ...
    NSMutableArray *arrOfItems;
}
```

Then in your implementation file, you add your food to your array, save the Core Data context, then perform a fetch from Core Data and store the result into your class variable array:

```
// this method gets called when your button is pressed
-(void)addFoodToList
{
    Food *food = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Food"

    food.name = foodToListNameTextField.text;

    [managedObjectContext save:nil];

    // for simplicity sake, we're doing a simple table reload
    [self fetchData]; // see below
    [myTableView reloadData]; // reloads the table to include the newly added food 
}

-(void)fetchData
{
    // core data fetch request of all items we want to display in the list

    arrOfItems = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request .... ];
}
```

Note you should return the number of items in your class variable array in this table view delegate method:

```
// View Controller implementation file (.m file)
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(int)section
{
    // after adding the item to your arrOfItems and then doing a fetch request
    // earlier (see above code), this next statement would return the correct value
    return [arrOfItems count];
}
```

All that's left to do is in your UITableViewCellForRow method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString cellID = @"cellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithID:cellID];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithTableViewCellStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reusableIdentifier:cellID] autorelease];

        // init your element foodItemLabel
        foodTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:...];
        foodTitleLabel.tag = 1;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:foodTitleLabel];

        [foodTitleLabel release];
    }

    foodTitleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];

    FoodItem *foodItem = (FoodItem *)[arrOfItems objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.row];

    // display the food name
    foodTitleLabel.text = foodItem.title; 

    return cell;
}
```